# Execution time while changing attribute values in PyQGIS

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-3

Just want to ask if this is a normal run time when creating new attributes and writing the values of more than `30,000` features. This is for a script I'm writing.

```
Time to change attribute value: 0:03:44.954493
```

The process takes approximately `4` minutes just to execute this code

```
mem_layer.startEditing()
startendField = QgsField(fieldname1, QVariant.String)
durationField = QgsField(fieldname2, QVariant.String)
prov = mem_layer.dataProvider()
prov.addAttributes([startendField])
prov.addAttributes([durationField])
mem_layer.updateFields()
t0 = datetime.now()
i=0
for feat in mem_layer.getFeatures():
     #mem_layer.changeAttributeValue(feat.id(),newdatetimeIdx, 12345.67890)
     feat.setAttribute(fieldname1, startend_tbl[i])
     feat.setAttribute(fieldname2, duration_tbl[i])
     #feat[fieldname1] = startend_tbl[i]
     #feat[fieldname2] = duration_tbl[i]
     mem_layer.updateFeature(feat)
     i+=1
mem_layer.commitChanges()
t1 = datetime.now()
feedback.pushInfo('Time to change attribute value: {}'.format(str(t1-t0)))
```

I read somewhere that using the data provider is not the most efficient method but I don't have any idea what the other options are.

Comment: Side note, either you use the dataprovider to add/remove attributes/features or you use the editing session (startEditing,commitChanges). In your example, you are using both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried the provider method `prov.changeAttributeValues()` and it is a lot faster than the `setAttribute()` and `updateFeature()`. The process just takes `1` second! Now I don't need to wait `4` minutes every time I tinker with my code.

```
Time to change attribute value: 0:00:01.160000
```